# Pygame: Using colliderect in classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

This the the sprite class:

```
class Minion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


  def __init__(self, x, y):

      pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
      self.color = tuple([random.randrange(0, 256), random.randrange(0,   256), random.randrange(0, 256)])
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.minion = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 15, 25)
      pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, self.color, (self.x, self.y, 15, 25))
```

This is the code being used for a tower defense game. Now if a wanted to know if one Minion collided with another using a function like colliderect for the Rect object of each Minion, how would I do it?

Also, if there was another class which shot bullets(Rect objects), how would I detect the collision between them and the Minion?

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might know that each sprite consist of an **`image`** (which is drawn on a surface) and a **`rect` object** (sets location and size (!) of the image).

Add a `rect` object for your sprite in your `__init__` method. This is very simple, because the `pygame.draw.anyObject()` method returns always a `rect` instance which represents the position and size of the drawn object:

```
self.collideRect = pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, self.color, (self.x, self.y, 15, 25))
```

Therefore you don´t need the line `self.minion = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 15, 25)`.

To check if **one minion** (i.e. the `rect` object) collides with another minion, you could do something like this in your main game loop:

```
if minion1.collideRect.colliderect(minion2.collideRect) == True:
    pass #do something
```

If you have **more than one object** (e.g. minions or bullets in a list called `objList`) you can use the `.collidelist()` method instead. This method returns the *index* of the first collision found. If no collisions are found `-1` is returned:

```
colIndex = minion1.collideRect.collidelist([obj.collideRect for obj in objList])
#do something with the object in objList[colIndex]
```